# Print matched pattern lines side by side

Tags: shell-script

I have text file which has below lines

```
From:   arkit Corp. <do-not-reply@123.ac>

Sent:   Friday, June 16, 2017 6:35 PM

To:     User Name

Subject:        arkit Corp.: activity alert.


                 <http:// arkit.co.in/>

ACTIVITY ALERT FOR:

Ravi


https:// arkit.co.in/ Path Read (03/07/2017)

Path: /website/upload/file.txt


https:// arkit.co.in/ Path Read (04/07/2017)

Path: /website/upload/file1.txt



        Copyright ▒ 2017 arkit Corp.. All Rights Reserved.
```

I would like to print them as below

```
https:// arkit.co.in/ Path Read (03/07/2017) Path: /website/upload/file.txt
https:// arkit.co.in/ Path Read (04/07/2017) Path: /website/upload/file1.txt
```

Can any one suggest how can i print side-by-side

Comment: `paste` is your friend here. Specifically, `paste -sd' ' yourtxtfile`

Comment: Not only those two lines i have others lines in text file as well.

Comment: @RaviAnkam explain the logic by which you want to combine... do you have empty lines in input file?

Comment: what does mean **matched pattern** lines in your case?

Comment: If the next line after `https` need to be joined, then `awk '/http:*/{a=$0; getline; print a,$0;next}' filename` will work.

Comment: Matched pattern means where ever string starts with https its end of line will append with Path: string. which means two pattern of line should match and append.

Comment: these clarifying comments should be edited into the question; otherwise they could easily be overlooked, leaving an unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to parse the whole message, use "addresses" like this:

```
sed -n '/https:/h;/Path:/{H;g;s/\n/ /p;}' yourfile
```

Don't output by default (`-n`). Put a line starting with `https:` in the hold buffer, then for the `Path:` line, append it to the hold buffer, move it to the pattern space and replace the newline with a whitespace.

Or a different approach:

```
sed -e '/^https:/!d;:a' -e '$!N;/Path:/!ba' -e 's/\n\n*/ /' yourfile
```

This means: If the line doesn't start with `https:`, delete it (`/^https:/!d`). Else start a loop (`:a`) to add new lines if there are any (`$!N`), until we added the `Path:` line. `/Path:/!ba`. Finally replace newlines with a whitespace to put everything in one line (`s/\n\n*/ /`).

Comment: This approach is working, if i have only single email as text. but i have multiple lines in single file where it's not working. As i posted only single email content like wise i have lot of emails and all the email content in single text file.

Comment: I can't see why it could fail with as many emails in one file as you like. Can you expand your question to contain a case that fails?

Comment: Its printing from Path: first line is not printing.  

Path: /RaviKumar/Delivey From Ravi/ARK-23231498216 R6 (05.05.07)-Jpk J.xlsx

Comment: I don't understand. Please include the non-working sample in the question, so that I can process your sample and see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

If you want to break on empty lines,

```
awk '{printf $0; printf ($0=="")? "\n" : " "}' /path/to/file.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `printf $0`: print the currently line (with no newline)
- `printf ($0=="")? "\n" : " "`: If the current line is empty `($0=="")?`, then print a newline `"\n"`, otherwise print a space `" "`.
- N.B. this prints a trailing space on the final line, which may or may not be a problem for you.

## Option 2

However, if you just want to break on every third line,

```
awk '{printf $0; printf (NR%3=="0")? "\n" : " "}' /path/to/file.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `(NR%3=="0")`: here the conditional tests if the line number `NR` mod `3` is equal to zero. i.e. it will print a newline every three input lines, otherwise just print a space.

Answer (score 0):

Method-1: We invoke Perl in paragraph mode `-00` and make ORS=\n `-l` and enable the file read-in mode with explicit print `-n`. The current record `$_` which begins with https:// is picked and it's end-of-record position is filled with the next record `<>`. Finally the newlines in this appended current record are deleted and what remains is printed to stdout. The ORS will be appended to the current record.

```
perl -ln -00e 's/$/$".<>/e and print tr/\n//dr if m|^https://|' file.txt
```

In this method, we set up a loop when we encounter the https:// line and keep appending empty lines we find along the way to the first non-empty. All this time we keep deleting those empty lines.

```
sed -ne '
   \|^https://|!d
   :loop
      N
      s/\n$//
   tloop
   s/\n/ /p
' file.txt
```

---

### Output

```
https:// arkit.co.in/ Path Read (03/07/2017) Path: /website/upload/file.txt
https:// arkit.co.in/ Path Read (04/07/2017) Path: /website/upload/file1.txt
```